# SetTimeout and clearTimeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have written this js function for calling ajax for every 15 seconds duration.
But it should be limited based on other conditions

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var disableReload = '<s:property value="#session[\'EXECUTOR\'] == null" />';
  var tId = window.setTimeout(function () { 
    location.reload(true);
   //alert(disableReload);
   if(disableReload){
       //alert("Clearing");
       clearTimeout(tId);
   }else{
    var url = 'my.action';
    var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
    var params = Form.serialize(form) + '&ms=' +  new Date().getTime();
    var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(url, {method: 'post', parameters: params, onComplete: showResponseAction} );
   }
 }, 15 * 1000);
</script>
```

but when disableReload is true; clearTimeout is not clearing/removing reload function.

How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your intention, then something like this is what you need:

```
var disableReload = false; // toggle this to false, on AJAX response(?) to stop repeats

var repeat = function()
{
    if(disableReload) 
    {
       clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
    else
    {
       var url = 'my.action';
       var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
       var params = Form.serialize(form) + '&ms=' +  new Date().getTime();
       var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(url, {method: 'post', parameters: params, onComplete: showResponseAction} );
    }
}

var intervalID = window.setInterval(repeat, 1000);
```

Comment: Did you miss some code. I can see if condition is bit wrong. during else part. location.reload(true) will reload the page right

Comment: @NitinGurram Yes, and I copied that from your code. Like I said, I tried to understand your objective from reading your code, as the question was not very clear.

Comment: My requirement is to call an ajax function for every 1 min (let's say). But I should be able to disable this based on disableReload variable. All of these things should happen without any button clicks or some other user based operations

Comment: @NitinGurram Understood. I have updated my answer. You will just have to somehow toggle 'disableReload' var to stop repeats. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Because, looking at your code, it seems like your page is getting refreshed before clearTimeout is being called.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly what you're expecting to happen here.

You're calling the `clearTimeout` method *within the timeout function* - that is, that code will only be called when the timeout has already elapsed, and the closure is run.

The point of clearTimeout is to stop a running timeout, so that the registered closure is not called.  Calling it if (and only if) the timeout has just fired is not going to achieve anything.

I can only suggest you think again about under what conditions you want to cancel the pending reload - and rearranging your code such that `clearTimeout` is called when these cases are triggered, rather than *after* the reload has already happened.

---

Edit: Ah, it seems that you don't necessarily want to cancel the *timeout* itself, rather you want to disable the reload from happening based on the result of the variable.  There are a couple of ways I see to do this:

1. Whenever you would set `disableReload = true`, call `clearTimeout(tId)` instead.  So long as `tId` has the same scope/visibility as `disableReload` this should be possible as a drop-in replacement.
2. Change the logic of your timeout function so that the reload itself is conditional on `disableReload`.

The former is probably the cleanest option - there's little point in keeping a timeout running that you know is going to do nothing, and it also avoids the question of what happens if something sets `disableReload` back to false before the timeout elapses.

But the latter is a less substantial change to your existing code, and likely easier to grasp:

```
window.setTimeout(function () { 
   if (!disableReload) {
      location.reload(true); 

      // I think these are dependent on the disableReload variable too?
      // If not you can move them outside the if block
      var url = 'my.action';
      var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
      var params = Form.serialize(form) + '&ms=' +  new Date().getTime();
      var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(url, {method: 'post', parameters: params, onComplete: showResponseAction} );
   }
}, 15 * 1000);
```

This way, if `disableReload` is true, then nothing happens when the timeout closure fires.

Comment: Yes. My requirement is to call an ajax function for every 1 min (let's say). But I should be able to disable this based on disableReload variable. All of these things should happen without any button clicks or some other user based operations

Comment: I see - I've updated my answer based on your comment, as it sounds like you don't necessarily need to cancel the timeouts at all.

Comment: @NitinGurram I still don't understand why you want to do a `location.reload` along with your AJAX request.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `disableReload` variable is static (never written to again). If that's true, why are you setting the timeout in the first place? Just wrap the whole `var tId = window.setTimeout...` in an `if (!disableReload)`.

Comment: After calling ajax, based on response I am changing it's value. that' too long conditions and code doesn't affect this. so I didn't post that part

Comment: @NitinGurram That's after you're already in the function that was delayed. You're not using `setInterval`, so it's not going to repeat. At that stage the only thing you need to do is `return` from the `function`. You're also reloading the page at the start of the function which is going to reset everything.

Comment: oops.. I am newbie to js and learning by googling. Can you please write js code for this case based on my requirement. I will learn :)

Comment: I think you need to drop your `location.reload(true)`, change your `window.setTimeout` to a `window.setInterval` (this one repeats), then you should be able to use the function much like you are now, but using `clearInterval` rather than `clearTimeout`.